# Trouble passing command line arguments to Ruby script and reading from command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

I've narrowed the problem down to the following simple code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

print "Enter your name: "
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello #{name}"
```

This works fine when called from the OS X Terminal like this `ruby a.rb`. However passing a command line argument like this `ruby a.rb 123` causes this error:

```
a.rb:4:in `gets': No such file or directory - 123 (Errno::ENOENT)
    from a.rb:4
```

My goal is to pass command line arguments to a script **and** read input from the keyboard.

**What is causing the above error?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can same program in ruby accept input from user as well as command line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399618/how-can-same-program-in-ruby-accept-input-from-user-as-well-as-command-line-argu)

Comment: You should probably look into using [OptionParser](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/optparse/frames). It will handle the clean-up for you and gives you a lot of command-line processing without a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: [How can same program in ruby accept input from user as well as command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399618/how-can-same-program-in-ruby-accept-input-from-user-as-well-as-command-line-argu)

Just had to do `ARGV.clear` before using `gets`.

Comment: This was helpful. It seems to be a problem for me in ruby 2.0.0-p247 but not in other rubies or patch versions.